# In Laravel can I set a default context for the Log facade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the `Log::` facade a lot and have a helper class called `LogHelper` which provide me with a static method `LogHelper::context()` which include many key values I need to track the requests. But having to type it every time for each usage make it error prune and fill not so efficient.

I'm looking for a way to inject the values by default, and allow me to overwrite them if needed specifically.

At the moment this is how I use it,

```php
Log::debug('Request Started', LogHelper::context());
```

what I'm looking for is to inject the context by default

```php
Log::debug('Request Started');
```

and have the option to overwrite it, if need it:

```php
Log::debug('Request Started', ['more' => 'context'] + LogHelper::context());
```

PS, the `LogHelper::context()` return a simple `key => value` array which include some staff i need to debug requests, and the reason it do not use the values directly in the message is because i log to graylog as structured data, and this way i can filter by any key.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this issue by using the [tap](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#customizing-monolog-for-channels) functionality and `$logger->withContext()` (note: the latter was added in Laravel 8.49).

You want to create a new class which contains your context logic. I've created an extra Logging folder in app/ in which my logging customizations sit.

`app/Logging/WithAuthContext.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Illuminate\Log\Logger;

class WithAuthContext
{
    public function __invoke(Logger $logger)
    {
        $logger->withContext([
            'ip' => request()?->ip(),
            'ua' => request()?->userAgent(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Depending on which logging channel(s) you use, you will have to add the class to each one you want to add context to. So in `app/config/logging.php`:

```
<?php

use App\Logging\WithAuthContext;
use Monolog\Handler\NullHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\SyslogUdpHandler;

return [
// ...
    'channels' => [
        // ...
        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'tap' => [WithAuthContext::class],
        ],
        // ...
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but it is not pretty. You can create a custom monolog logger driver. The process is described at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#creating-monolog-handler-channels.

Here's a possible implementation:

```
class ContextEnrichingLogger extends \Monolog\Handler\AbstractHandler {
 
    
    private $logger;

    public function __construct($level = Monolog\Logger::DEBUG, bool $bubble = true, $underlyingLogger = 'single') {
       $this->logger = Log::driver($underlyingLogger);
    }

    public function handle(array $record) {
        $record['context'] += LogHelper::context();
        return $this->logger->handle($record);
    }  

}
```

Then register this as a custom logger in your `config/logging.php`:

```
return [ 
    'default' => 'enriched',
    //...
    'channels' => [
       // ...
       'enriched' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => ContextEnrichingLogger::class,
            'level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            "with" => [
                "underlyingLogger" => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'single')
            ]
        ]

   ]
];
```

I haven't tested this particular one but this is how I've defined other custom loggers.

Note, this is probably also achievable via a custom formatter though I think it's probably the same trouble.